# Fill missing months with zeros on a Groupby

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns:

[image]

The `Posting Date` goes from 2018-01-01 (yyyy-mm-dd) until 2022-10-30 (yyyy-mm-dd)
I want to group my dataframe by `Material` and by `Posting Date` date with granurality of 1 month and for the months within the `Posting Date` range, fill the Total_Sum with zeros.
So i need my output to be somthing similar to this:

```
    Material        Posting Date      Total_Sum
0   E7400R101012      2018-01            0
1   E7400R101012      2018-02            0
2   E7400R101012      2018-03            0
3   E7400R101012      2018-04            0
4   E7400R101012      2018-05            0
5   E7400R101012      2018-06            2
6   E7400R101012      2018-07            0
7   E7400R101012      2018-08            0
8   E7400R101012      2018-09            0
9   E7400R101012      2018-10            0
10  E7400R101012      2018-11            3
11  E7400R101012      2018-12            0
--                     ---
nn  E7400R101012      2022-10            0
nn  NEW CODE          2018-01            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column `Posting Date` to month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), so possible create [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) by minimal and maximal values and create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html).

Then aggregate `sum` and add missing pairs by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1['Posting Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Posting Date']).dt.to_period('m')
periods = pd.period_range(df1['Posting Date'].min(), df1['Posting Date'].max(), freq='m')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['Material'].unique(), 
                                  periods], 
                                  names=['Material', 'Posting Date'])

df2 = (df1.groupby(['Material', 'Posting Date']).sum()
          .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
          .reset_index())
```